# MVC 2.0 dynamic routing for category names in an e-store

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, c#-4.0, url-routing

I'm currently working on an e-store using ASP.NET MVC 2.0. I already got most of it up and running, but the part that's been bothering me is routing. I want this:

http://mystore.somewhere/my-category-1/

So far I've been able to solve it by using:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Category",
            "{alias}/{pageNumber}",
            new { controller = "Categories", action = "Browse", pageNumber = 1 });
```

But this catches way too much than just what I'd like.

After reading through some questions and answers around this site, I found a particulary interesting solution that would require me to programatically register a route for each of my categories, so in essence I'd be doing

```
 foreach (var c in Categories)
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                c.Name,
                "{" + c.Alias + "}/{action}/...anything else",
                new { controller = "Category", action = "Index" }).RouteHandler = new CateegoryRouteHandler(c);
        }
```

What do you think? Is this a good idea? I'm probably going to have about 200 categories, is that too much "routes" to have in the routing table? Would you suggest another solution?

Thanks.

Regards,
 Anže

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A single route with a dynamic constraint might be a more elegant solution.  Just set up a constraint that only matches your categories.

```
     routes.MapRoute(
        "Category",
        "{alias}/{pageNumber}",
        new { controller = "Categories", action = "Browse", alias = UrlParameter.Optional, pageNumber = 1 },
        new { alias = new CategoryMatchConstraint() } );


 public class CategoryMatchConstraint : IRouteConstraint
 {
      public bool Match( HttpContextBase httpContext,
                         Route route,
                         string parameterName,
                         RouteValueDictionary values,
                         RouteDirection routeDirection )
      {
           var category = values.Values[parameterName] as string;
           if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(category))
           {
                return false;
           }
           using (var db = new MyDatabaseContext())
           {
                return db.Categories.Any( c => c.Name == category );
           }
      }
}
```

Comment: Oh great! That worked just like a charm! Didn't know about the route constraints. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hello @tvanfosson, what about the performance if there are 50K categories. As far as i know there is a route table caching or something like that but in any case it checks from db.