# URL just isn't displaying what I want

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url, asp.net-mvc-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I accomplish this type of URL in ASP.Net MVC2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424583/how-can-i-accomplish-this-type-of-url-in-asp-net-mvc2)

I want to create HTML links like:

```
/Auctions/Clothes
/Auctions/Electronics
/Auctions/Real Estate
```

Here's how I'm constructing the links:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Ropa", "Index", "Anuncios", new { category = "Ropa" }, new { })</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Libros", "Index", "Anuncios", new { category = "Libros" }, new { })</li>
```

The problems is the links are being used like this:

```
http://localhost:8589/Anuncios?category=Libros
```

I want my URLS to be nice looking, as such I'd like the above to be like:

```
/Anuncios/Libros
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this? Here's the ActionResult method, and to clarify, this is doing exactly what I want it to do. It works, except the URL is horrible.

```
public ActionResult Index(string category)
{            
    AuctionRepository auctionRepo = new AuctionRepository();
    var auctions = auctionRepo.FindAllAuctions().Where(a => a.Subcategory.Category.Name == category);
    return View(auctions);
}
```

Comment: how is your route configured?

Comment: Not configured at all (in the Global.asax file) if you mean that. Suggestions?

Comment: if you havent configured any routes, how do you expect MVC to know how you would like your urls to look like?

Comment: Is'nt [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424583/how-can-i-accomplish-this-type-of-url-in-asp-net-mvc2) the same question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please have a look at this question for implementing your requirement.

- [MVC 2.0 dynamic routing for category names in an e-store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325140/mvc-2-0-dynamic-routing-for-category-names-in-an-e-store)

**EDIT:**

create a new HTML helper that you will use to render the menu like this

```
public static class MyMenuHelper {
    public static string MyMenu(this HtmlHelper helper) {
        List<Category> categories = GetCategories();
        foreach ( Category c in categories ) {
            helper.RouteLink( c.Name, "AuctionCategoryDetails", new { categoryName = c.Name } );
        }
    }
}
```

Finally in your _Layout page use it like this

```
@Html.MyMenu
```

Comment: Hi Lorenzo, thanks a bunch for your help. The variable you're calling 'html' isn't avaialable. Maybe a typo? I also see the method returns a string, but it never returns anything. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes! it was a typo. It should be "helper". I have edited the answer

Comment: Please be careful that you cannot have spaces in the url. So if this is your case simply remove the space from the category name that you put on the third parameter of RouteLink

Comment: Hm... the 'helper' variable doesn't have a RouteLink method. I've tried referencing both System.Web.WebPages.Html; and System.Web.Mvc; but the method isn't there.

Comment: `namespace System.Web.Mvc.Html`

Comment: @Serg - i really just don't get you. You ask a question, which i answered - and you accepted, then you ask another one? Then you accept this one, then you write a comment on my other answer saying your stuck? Not meaning to sound rude, but you really need to start thinking about what your issue is, explaning it best you can in the question, then only accept the answer once your problem is solved. It seems you ask a new question anytime you need to write a line of code. Again, not meaning to sound rude - but that's what it's feeling like from over here.

Comment: @Lorenzo: Yeah that's the wierd bit. I read the page over on MSDN, and I'm sure I'm refering the needed namespace. I'll keep testing.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add some routes so MVC knows how you would prefer the links to look like. Its not like it can read your thoughts, or make coffee.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Anuncios",                 // Route name
        "Anuncios/{category}",      // URL with parameters
        new { category = "Index" }  // Parameter defaults
    );
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. it just explain how to create a route...

Comment: how can that not be an answer... his problem is that he haven't created any routes, so i show him how to add routes so the ActionLink method can render the desired urls.

Comment: His problem is clearly (very clearly) stated in the first line. And it does'nt seems to me that he's looking on how to create a generic route. Moreover the solution is not as you described it because your solution suppose to create a variable number of routes (one for each category) and so potentially lead to multiple modification of the code when a new category would get added

Comment: @Serg: did you try the answer marked in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424583/how-can-i-accomplish-this-type-of-url-in-asp-net-mvc2)? Why it does'nt fit your requirement?

Comment: @Lorenzo its hard to deduct precisely HOW he wants his urls to look like, but i have to assume the first three links has nothing to do with his real app, and that its /Anuncios/{category} that is what he wants. And by looking at his ActionLink() calls i tried to create a satisfactory route.

Comment: @Lorenzo: That solutions doesn't help me particularly because I'm creating all of these Html.ActionLink() in the _Layout.cshtml file. I don't know how to have a controller act on this layout file.

Comment: @Serg: I really dont see the problem Serg. You already have a Controller and an Action. In your view page you just need to write `<%: Html.RouteLink("Clothes", "AuctionCategoryDetails", new { categoryName = "Clothes" });`

Comment: @Pauli: Basically he wants to create some link that ends up with the category name and all these links shall be mapped to the same route. The first three links is exactly what he wants. he should use `RouteLink` instead of `ActionLink` in the view

Comment: @Lorenzo how are you to decide what he wants? How do you interpret "I want my URLS to be nice looking, as such I'd like the above to be like: /Anuncios/Libros" then?

Comment: @Pauli: I did not decided anything. I have just read the question. And I invite you to read it again and slowly...

Comment: @Serg: even my answer below is not working for you?

Comment: @Lorenzo: I'm sorry, it's just not clicking for me. It might seem obvious to you, but for me it's just absolute mental block about this particular case. How would you set things up so a list of Categories are displayed on every single page on your website? Similar to Amazons categories on the left hand side.

Comment: @Serg: Let's start with a simple link: open up your _Layout.cshtml and just write somewhere `<%: Html.RouteLink("Clothes", "AuctionCategoryDetails", new { categoryName = "Clothes" });` This would create a link on every page that use ?Layout.cshtml like `<a href="/Auctions/Clothes">Clothes</a>`. I suppose that you have a single controller action as described in your yesterday post that will handle the link click. Does this work?

Comment: @Lorenzo: Sweet shamma lamma. Finally it clicked. I can't thank you enough man, jesus. This has been gnawing at me for three days now! Now the final step for me to sleep in peace: I can now create the links manually but how would I approach a dynamic retrieving and rendering of categories if _layout.cshtml DOESN'T USE A CONTROLLER? I can't use Model.Categories or any of that it seems.

Comment: @Serg: Good! The easiest way would be simply to call a method from inside your _Layout file that return a list of categories :) You can even use jquery for this but it is not really needed

Comment: @Lorenzo: How would I call this method? Any code samples available or a name so I can Google it? Thanks a lot for your help. I wish I could upvote you 50 times.

Comment: @Serg: have a look at my answer edit. `GetCategories()` is a custom method that reads your categories from database and return them in form of a list or any other container element. hope this helps!